# How to calculate average values of columns by bins?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
bins    var1   var2
[0, 2)  10     22
[2, 6)  15     20
[2, 6)  16     20
[2, 6)  14     19
[0, 2)  9      23
[0, 2)  10     22
[0, 2)  8      22
```

I want to estimate an average `var1` and `var2` per `bins` value.

This is an expected result:

```
bins    var1   var2
[0, 2)  9.25   22.25
[2, 6)  15     19.7
```

How can I do it? This is what I tried, but it does not return an expected result:

```
import pandas as pd

avg_bins = pd.DataFrame

for c in df.columns:
  b = df.groupby("bins").agg({c: "mean"}).reset_index()
  if avg_bins.empty:
    avg_bins = b
  else:
    avg_bins = pd.concat([avg_bins,b], axis=0)

avg_per_ri_bin
```

Comment: So basically: `df.groupby('bins').agg('mean')` ?

Comment: @JonClements: This will return an average over `var1` and `var2`. I need to split `var1` and `var2` into different columns.

Comment: Errr nope... it won't do that... have you tried the above? It gives you separate columns...

Comment: @JonClements: Oh, I was overcomplicating the things:) Thanks.

Comment: So, especially your last comment suggests closing because of problem cannot be reproduced anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could do either of these two (first less code, second more basic)

```
df2 = df.groupby(by='bins').agg('mean')
```

OR

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
df2['bins']=df['bins'].unique()

for i,row in df2.iterrows():
    df2.loc[i]['var1'] = df[df['bins']==row['bins']]['var1'].mean()
    df2.loc[i]['var2'] = df[df['bins']==row['bins']]['var2'].mean()
```